# Timestamp is different for the same table in hive-cli & presto-cli

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto

I am getting different timestamps for the same table in hive-cli & presto-cli.

**table structure for the table:**

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                   createtab_stmt                   |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `mea_req_201`(               |
|   `mer_id` bigint,                                 |
|   `mer_from_dttm` timestamp,                       |
|   `mer_to_dttm` timestamp,                         |
|   `_c0` bigint,                                    |
|   `a_number` string,                               |
|   `b_number` string,                               |
|   `time_stamp` timestamp,                          |
|   `duration` bigint)                               |
| PARTITIONED BY (                                   |
|   `partition_col` bigint)                          |
| ROW FORMAT SERDE                                   |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'      |
| STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                              |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'  |
| OUTPUTFORMAT                                       |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' |
| LOCATION                                           |
|   'hdfs://hadoop5:8020/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/mea_req_201' |
| TBLPROPERTIES (                                    |
|   'TRANSLATED_TO_EXTERNAL'='TRUE',                 |
|   'bucketing_version'='2',                         |
|   'external.table.purge'='TRUE',                   |
|   'spark.sql.create.version'='2.4.0.7.1.4.0-203',  |
|   'spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols'='1',      |
|   'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1',         |
|   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1625496239')            |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

While running from hive-cli the output is:

[image]

While from presto-cli:

[image]

in mer_from_dttm col, there's a time difference but for other timestamps columns, dates are exactly the same. Note this time difference behaviour is the same when done from presto-jdbc also. I believe this got nothing to do with timezone because if it was timezone, the time difference should be across all timestamp columns, not just one. Please provide some resolution.

**Some Facts:**

- Presto server version: 0.180
- Presto Jdbc version: 0.180
- hive.time-zone=Asia/Calcutta
- In Presto jvm.config:  -Duser.timezone=Asia/Calcutta
- Client TimeZone: Asia/Calcutta

---

**Edit 1:**
Sorted the query with mer_id to ensure both queries are outputting the same set of rows, However, the erroneous behavior still remains the same.

- While Running from hive-cli:
  [image]
- While Running from presto-cli:
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Presto 0.180 is really old. It was released in 2017, and many bugs have been fixed along the way.

I would suggest you try with a recent version. In particular, recent versions of [Trino](https://trino.io/) ([formerly known as PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)) had a lot work done around handling of timestamp data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Upgraded Presto to [0.256(latest)](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.256.html). However, the issue still exists. https://imgur.com/dksGE0o

Comment: Did you try Trino 359 (the latest version as of today)?

Comment: I can't use Trino 359. it requires Java 11 & we are running our project on Java 8. However, I tried with a lower version of Trino but getting the same erroneous resultset.

Comment: Do you have custom code running within Presto? Otherwise, you can run Trino with a separate JVM than your main project. You can install JVMs side by side.

Comment: Yes, I have certain custom-defined presto UDfs in the project classpath. However, for testing purposes, I brought up Trino 359 with Java 11. And I am getting proper results in trino-cli. https://imgur.com/J0fsErV. Thanks for ur help.
Are you aware of any PRs that might have fixed this issue? Something that we can patch into an existing version of PrestoDB because upgrading to Trino with java 11 isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use order by to see exact rows in each of clients.

```
SELECT `mer_id`,`mer_from_dttm`, `mer_to_dttm`, `time_stamp` FROM mea_req_201 ORDER BY `mer_id`;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, however, I am using exact rows, verified

Comment: Presto with orderby: https://pasteboard.co/Ka2DjZj.png
HIve with order by: https://pasteboard.co/Ka2EjP6.png

Comment: It was very useful to edit **your question**, separate with EDIT1----- line and add this two pictures. Importantly, add `mer_id` in your select to see what is the exact rows returned.